# How to handling heap Space without increase JVM?

Tags: java, heap-memory

Modifying MP3 file as below is causing Out of Memory error . is there anyway i can do the below operation more efficiently ( i.e., using lesser memory)

```
public void BacaMP3(){
    String a = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/MP3/21.waltz-cut.mp3";
 String bitMP3="";
    try {
         File song = new File(a);
         FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(song);

         int  input = 0;
         System.out.println("Creating file ...");
         while (input != -1) {
             input = file.read();
             count++;
             if (input==-1)bitMP3="#";
             else{
                 bitMP3 = Integer.toBinaryString(input);
                 while(bitMP3.length()<8){
                    bitMP3="0"+bitMP3;
                 }
             }

             area1.append(bitMP3+"\n");

         }
         System.out.println(count);
         file.close();

         System.out.println("Done");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error Ã¢â‚¬â€ " + e.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Your question needs to be re-phrased for us to understand the issue. Do you mean you are running out of memory when you execute the above program? If so what is min/max heap that you are using and how big the mps file is. On the sidenode, you are using String in your program for  bitMP3, use StringBuffer instead

Comment: i want to do MP3 Processing, i want to change some bit in MP3....but when i do this....my memory is running out..i try to increase JVM but its still not enough.

Comment: Run it using StringBuffer or StringBuilder as suggested in the comment. What is the heap size you are using and what is the file size that you are dealing with

Comment: the readMp3 method is the first step, the next step is processing MP3 bit. When i run the next step i use 1500M of memory and 6MB MP3 size...

Comment: `System.out.println("Error Ã¢â‚¬â€ " + e.toString());`  Note that `e.printStackTrace()` is 1) shorter 2) more informative 3) less incomprehensible ..than that statement.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter

```
while(bitMP3.length()<8){
    bitMP3="0"+bitMP3; // Here you are creating two string till count is less than 8 move it to string buffer
}

area1.append(bitMP3+"\n"); // Here you are already using string buffer why doing string concatenation then change to area1.append(bitMP3).append("\n");
```